# dataframeからuser_id毎にデータを分離させuser_idがファイル名となるcsvファイルを作り指定フォルダに書き込みしたい

Tags: python, python3

dataframe型のビックデータがあります。
このデータからuser_id毎にデータを分離し、user_idがファイル名になるcsvファイルとして書き込みしたいです。

出来るところまでコードを組んでみましたが、ディレクトリのパスの指定からディレクトリ名の設定方法について教えてもらえますか？

```
user_unique = list(set(df["user_id"]))
for i in range(len(user_unique)):
    a=df[df["user_id"]==user_unique[i]]
    a=a.sort_values(by='utc')
    a=a.reset_index(drop=True)
    dflist=pd.DataFrame(a)
    dflist.to_csv(str(user_unique[i])+'.csv',index=False)
```

**対象のデータ**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pandas.DataFrameの[groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)を使えば少し簡単に出来るでしょう。

フォルダ・ファイル名操作はフォルダが既に有れば文字列の連結だけで出来ます。
作成する場合は[pathlib](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/pathlib.html)などですね。

例えばこれらの記事です。
[Looping over groups in a grouped dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45797633/9014308)
[Python、pathlibモジュールを使う](https://narito.ninja/blog/detail/72/)

上記にならえば、以下のように考えられます。(もう少し工夫すれば行数は削減出来そうですが)

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

targetfolder = Path('C:/WorkSpace/')
targetfolder.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True) # フォルダを作成する場合
for user_id, grouped in df.groupby('user_id'):
    dfwork = grouped.sort_values('utc')
    dfwork = dfwork.reset_index(drop=True)
    filename = Path(targetfolder, (user_id + '.csv'))
    dfwork.to_csv(filename, index=False)
```

Comment: 助かりました。groupby機能教えてくださいありがとうございます。本当に簡単に使えますね。

Comment: ちなみに以前の質問でもそうですが、サンプルデータもスクリーンショットでは無くテキスト化した方が良いですね。検討・回答する際の手間が大幅に省けます。

Comment: 良いアドバイスありがとうございます。